# How to serialize cleaned_data if it contains models?

Tags: django, json, serialization

I'm trying to serialize some form data so that I can stuff it into a hidden field until the user is ready to submit the whole form (think of a wizard).

I'm trying this:

```
print simplejson.dumps(vehicle_form.cleaned_data)
```

But I keep getting errors like this:

```
<VehicleMake: Honda> is not JSON serializable
```

Really I just need it to output the PK for "Honda".

This doesn't work either:

```
print serializers.serialize('json', vehicle_form.cleaned_data)
```

Gives:

```
'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Presumably because it's iterating over the keys, which are all strings, whereas I think it expects a queryset, which I don't have.

So how do I do this?

---

Okay, so far I've come up with this:

```
from django.utils.simplejson import JSONEncoder, dumps, loads
from django.utils.functional import curry
from django.db.models import Model
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
from django.core.serializers import serialize

class DjangoJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Model):
            return obj.pk
        elif isinstance(obj, QuerySet):
            return loads(serialize('json', obj, ensure_ascii=False))
        return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

json_encode = curry(dumps, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
json_decode = loads
```

Based on the answers I found [here][1]. Now I'm trying this:

```
json = json_encode(vehicle_form.cleaned_data)
data = json_decode(json)
vehicle = Vehicle(**data)
```

The first 2 lines work perfectly, but the 3rd results in an exception:

```
Cannot assign "3": "Vehicle.model" must be a "VehicleModel" instance.
```

Getting close! Not sure how to deal with this one though...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but I don't know of a better way:

```
try:
    vehicle_data = simplejson.loads(request.POST['vehicle_data'])
except ValueError:
    vehicle_data = []
vehicle_data.append(vehicle_form.raw_data())
request.POST['vehicle_data'] = simplejson.dumps(vehicle_data)
```

It grabs the JSON data from hidden field in your form and decodes it into a Python dict. If it doesn't exist, it starts a new list. Then it appends the new raw/uncleaned data and re-encodes it and dumps it into the hidden field.

For this to work you need to either make a copy of the POST data (`request.POST.copy()`) so that it becomes mutable, or hack it like I did: `request.POST._mutable = True`

In my form template I put this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="vehicle_data" value="{{request.POST.vehicle_data}}" />
```

And lastly, to access the raw data for a form I added these methods:

```
from django.forms import *

def _raw_data(self):
    return dict((k,self.data[self.add_prefix(k)]) for k in self.fields.iterkeys())

def _raw_value(self, key, value=None):
    if value is None:
        return self.data[self.add_prefix(key)]
    self.data[self.add_prefix(key)] = value

Form.raw_data = _raw_data
Form.raw_value = _raw_value
ModelForm.raw_data = _raw_data
ModelForm.raw_value = _raw_value
```

Since `.data` returns too much data (in fact, it just returns the POST data you initially passed in), plus it's got the prefixes, which I didn't want.

Comment: Wow, that's quite a lot of hacks =) Have you checked django-formwizard (http://django-formwizard.readthedocs.org/)? It basically allows you to specify a sequence of forms and handles data storage between the steps. You can have a ModelForm there, too, or a formset, if you have multiple model instances.

Comment: @Anton: Well... it's not really a wizard, that was just the easiest way to explain it. Really it's a form with a subform where you can add as many items as you like. When you click "add" it posts all the data back to the same page, serializes the subform data into a hidden field and clears it so you can add another. And thus you have a JS-free "dynamic" form where you can add as many items as you like. Pretty cool IMO. And it's not *that* hacky... it actually makes for a pretty clean solution as oppose to the ones I was trying before.

Comment: @Anton: the "contents" list on that page... took me awhile to realize those were links. same color as normal text, and no underline til you hover..hrm.. also, how is that one advantageous over the one that comes with django? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/

Comment: Well, `django-formwizard` is actually going to become `contrib.formtools.wizard`, so if you're using latest development version of Django, then you can already use it, I guess. But if you're sticking with stable release of Django, use `django-formwizard` app (old contrib formwizard is no good).

Comment: @Anton: oh. fair enough. yeah, I'm running stable 1.3 right now.